# Hibernate generate wrong sql query for inserting child entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mariadb, hibernate-mapping

i have a one to many entity association model in this way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "father")
public class Father {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)", updatable = false)
    @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType")
    private UUID id;

    ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "father", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<AbstractChild> children = new ArrayList<>();

    ...
    

}




@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
        name="type",
        discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER,
        columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1) NOT NULL")
@Table(
    name = "child",
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"type", "name", "father_id"})
)
@IdClass(Child.class)
public abstract class AbstractChild implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    protected Locale locale;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    protected Father father;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "type", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    protected short mediaType;

    ...

}



@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class ConcreteChildOne extends AbstractChild {

    @Lob
    private String content;

    ...

}



@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class ConcreteChildTwo extends AbstractChild {

    @Column(name = "path")
    private String path;

    ...

}
```

Everything seems fine but when i save a Father entity with children, the values order in generated sql is wrong.

The insert query for the father is ok

```
insert 
    into
        father
        (description, name, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
```

has those binding parameters

- binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [description]
- binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [name]
- binding parameter [3] as [BINARY]  - [3bfac6e0-08ec-4f6b-a62a-5626ee6ab0e5]

But the insert query for the child is wrong

```
    insert 
    into
        tourist_informations
        (content, type, father_id, locale) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

- binding parameter [1] as [CLOB]     - [this is my content]
- binding parameter [2] as [BINARY]   - [3bfac6e0-08ec-4f6b-a62a-5626ee6ab0e5]
- binding parameter [3] as [SMALLINT] - [1]
- binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR]  - [en_EN]

The sql to create database is

```
    create table father (
        id BINARY(16) not null,
        description varchar(255),
        name varchar(150) not null,
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=InnoDB
    
    create table child (
        type TINYINT(1) NOT NULL ,
        locale varchar(255) not null,
        path varchar(255),
        content longtext,
        father_id BINARY(16) not null,
        primary key (father_id, type, locale)
    ) engine=InnoDB
    
    alter table tourist_informations 
       add constraint FKpem984v0clq1bsvubkkynoq7x 
       foreign key (father_id) 
       references father (id)
```

Someone as an idea why the order is wrong?
Thank you in advice.

Comment: Can you post the SQL used to create the tables?

Comment: Just edited the question with creational sql script

Comment: Ok, and the code for the `Child` class? Also, is there an incoherence defined in `name="media_type"` instead of `name="type"`?

Comment: it was a typo on this post, code is right. Child class has only equals and hashCode methods.

I'm using mariadb as database; could it be a bug of mariadb jdbc client? Version is 2.7.3

Comment: Please, post the Child class for a better understanding.

Comment: I think you need to use `@Embeddable`/`@EmbeddedId` for your composite key, instead of repeating `@Id`. I'm not sure how Hibernate works with multiple properties defined as `@Id`, but it's probably confused. You can check [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-composite-primary-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) on how to map composite primary keys.

Comment: Hibernate recognize field annotated with `@Id` as a composite key.
I prefere to not use `@Embeddable/@EmbeddedId`  because discriminator column is part of composite key.

Answer (score 0):

I think your mapping is wrong. It should be:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "father", orphanRemoval = true)
private List<AbstractChild> children = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a map that works:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "father")
public class Father {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)", updatable = false)
    @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType")
    private UUID id;

    ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "father", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<AbstractChild> children = new ArrayList<>();

    ...
    

}


@Embeddable
public class ChildID implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "type")
    protected short type;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    protected String name;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)", name = "father_id")
    @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType")
    private UUID fatherId;

    ...

}



@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
        name="type",
        discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER,
        columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1) NOT NULL")
@DiscriminatorOptions(force = true, insert = false)
@Table(
    name = "child",
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"type", "name", "father_id"})
)
@IdClass(Child.class)
public abstract class AbstractChild implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ChildID id;

    public AbstractChild() {
        this.id = new ChildID();
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("fatherId")
    protected Father father;

    ...

}



@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class ConcreteChildOne extends AbstractChild {

    @Lob
    private String content;

    public ConcreteChildOne() {
        super();
        this.getId().type = 1;
    }

    ...

}



@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class ConcreteChildTwo extends AbstractChild {

    @Column(name = "path")
    private String path;

    public ConcreteChildTwo() {
        super();
        this.getId().type = 2;
    }

    ...

}
```

Of course you can improve the code using delegate method to set type on embedde d id or pass it with super() into constructor but those things are details.

Hope that answer can help
Thank you all for your answer